# Does Mojave make old MacBook slower?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mojave

I have a MacBook on `El Capitan` with the following specs:

```
Early 2016
1.3 GHz Intel Core m7
8GB memory
Intel HD Graphics 515 1536 MB
SSD 500G (half used)
```

It is mainly used for writing Word documents and watching YouTube.

Does upgrading to Mojave make the MacBook slower?

Measuring:

CPU speed

GPU Speed

RAM Speed

Disk Speed

Boot time

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a 2013 MBP running Mojave. It’s showing no issues and works fine. No concerns on speed. I noted no apparent slowdown in anything after upgrading from High Sierra. I think you should be fine... I wouldn’t even consider a 2016 model to be “old” at this point.

A sided by side comparison shows Mojave actually been slightly faster overall, and much faster in Booting.

Reboot average times were 212 seconds in High Sierra but only 124 seconds in Mojave, that’s an 88-second improvement.

However, as with any new OS X, the performances from 3D party apps might be initially impacted till they provide updates to they products.

Example Adobe CS Premiere Pro is 2 seconds slower in opeing on Mojave.

Do not have "word processing apps" to compare to answers your question.

[image: Mojave vs High Sierra]

Comment: Hi, if you did not like my changes to your post, feel free to delete.

Comment: I fail to see how a hardware test - especially one that didn't even manage to measure the CPU score - can attest as to whether the OS is faster or not.

Comment: @dr.nixon Thanks for your info. I will upgrade to Mojave.